# Compare two text files using Groovy

Tags: groovy

Compare two text files using groovy in Jenkins slave machine. Sample text files are as follows.

Sample1.txt:

```
team_a, added
team_b, removed
team_c, added
```

Sample2.txt:

```
team_d, added
team_e, added
team_c, removed
```

Need to identify the change and should give the output as `team_c` has been removed.

Asking this question as being newbie to groovy.

Comment: but what is the question? what have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted your code, but say you are a newbie, so I'll talk you through an example:

```
// For simplicity, I won't use files, but a "heredoc"
Sample1txt = '''
team_a, added
team_b, removed
team_c, added
'''

Sample2txt =''' 
team_d, added
team_e, added
team_c, removed
'''

//get the data in a map each
Map a = [:]
Sample1txt.splitEachLine(",") { line -> a[line[0]] = line[1]}
Map b = [:]
Sample2txt.splitEachLine(",") { line -> b[line[0]] = line[1]}

//for each key value pair in the second map...
b.each {k, v ->
    //if the key exists (you didn't say what you want to do with new keys)
    if (a.containsKey(k)) {
        //and if the key's value is not equal to the same key's value in the first map 
        if (!b[k].equals(a[k])) {
            //print it
            println "${k} : ${v}" 
        }
    }
}
```

This is not a robust solution, but it will point you in the right direction.